# Solved: Product saving issue - images - unique constraint violation found - 2.4.2-p1

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, magento2.4, save

We face a unique constraint violation found error when we try to save the product. When we check the attribute code `'87'` in the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table, we see that it is the default Magento attribute for image.

Any idea how to solve this?

[2021-07-13 09:45:09] main.CRITICAL: Unique constraint violation found {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException(code: 0): Unique constraint violation found at /vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Update.php:121, Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\DuplicateException(code: 1062): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '270763-87-0' for key 'catalog_product_entity_varchar.CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` (`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `attribute_id` = VALUES(`attribute_id`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `value` = VALUES(`value`) at /vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:599, Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '270763-87-0' for key 'catalog_product_entity_varchar.CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` (`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `attribute_id` = VALUES(`attribute_id`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `value` = VALUES(`value`) at /vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '270763-87-0' for key 'catalog_product_entity_varchar.CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID' at /vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"}

**EDIT:**

Seems that when we remove the row with attribute `'87', '88', '89' and '136'` in the table `catalog_product_entity_varchar` for a product, (all attributes for the image roles, Base, Small Thumbnail and Swatch), we then can save the product again.

But then we face the issue, that we can not save the product image role as `thumbnail`, `small image` and `base image` anymore. Only the `swatch` role remains selected when the product is saved. We also tried it with a entire new simple product and face the same issue.

[image]

**Edit 2:**

We created a new attribute "test new role" with input type "Media Image" and added that to the attribute set. Uploaded a new image, selected all image roles, including this new role and saved the product. In that case "swatch" is not selected anymore, but now only the new created attribute. So I got no clue anymore, please help me out...

[image]

Comment: How did you created media image attribute can you please share the code coz i am getting error during setup upgrade. error like `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '15-Images' for key 'eav_attribute_group.EAV_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_NAME', query was: INSERT INTO `eav_attribute_group` (`attribute_set_id`, `attribute_group_name`, `sort_order`, `attribute_group_code`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that we hit the limit of 2147483647 for `INT`. So we ALTER the table `catalog_product_entity_varchar` with the following query;

```
ALTER TABLE catalog_product_entity_varchar MODIFY COLUMN value_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Some more info, seems to be a Magento 2 bug;
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28387